# Data History with sails js and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, sails.js

In the past I have been using aown node/express/mongo application. But in future projects I want to build on top of a framework such as sailsjs. On my projects I have used mongoose with the addon mongoose-version, which covers all data versioning (or data history) if you have it configured once.

Now my question is, if there is a comparable plugin as well for sails which tracks all changes done on my mongodb?

Thank you in advance!